# Keras/Machine Learning: Any pros and cons of flattening input data vs having a higher dimensional input?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am training a model that takes two 300d word vectors as an input. I was originally planning on supplying a 600d vector as the input data.

However, I noticed on the Keras datasets page: http://keras.io/datasets/

They use higher dimensional input data instead of flattening the input. For example, they represent a 32x32 RBG image with dimensions:  (3, 32, 32)

Should I do a (2,300) input or a (1,600) input? Does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It matters if and only if your model is a spatial model. Typical examples involve convolutional neural networks. Otherwise - if no spatial based module is used - data will be internally flattened either way.